# Unity changing to BG colour when I try to move

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on an offline two player shooter style game with a split screen. However, when I attatch my camera to my player, and run the game, as soon as I press my arrow keys to move, the screen turns into its BG colour and doesn't show anything else. I tried deactivating the movement script and the bug seemed to go away. Any ideas why this may be happening?

I expected the player to move as it was supposed to, but instead I could see nothing but the colour blue(background colour) on my screen while running the game. No ground, no walls, nothing. Just a colour.

Comment: is it a 2d game and you adjust the Z portion of your transform ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I will have to reply in this way. You didn't give us enough information or the code why it is happening. Not trying to be a little aggressive here since you're new but if you want us to help you, you need to give us some examples or code to see if we can find the issue.